# Wider width not being applied using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have the following scss code:

```
@import "core-navigation";
$sidebar-extend-img-width: 12px;
$sidebar-nav-item-height: 85px;
$sidebar-nav-item-padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

.re-core-nav-menu-wide {
  width: $core-nav-width-wide;
  @extend .re-core-nav-menu;
}

.re-core-nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: $core-nav-width;
  background-image: $core-nav-background-image;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;

  .helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  a {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
  }

  a:hover,
  a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:inherit;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-container {
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    width: $core-nav-width;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-container-settings {
    @extend .sidebar-nav-container;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-item {
    padding: $sidebar-nav-item-padding;
    height: $sidebar-nav-item-height;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-item.sidebar-logo {
    height: 110px;
  }

  .sidebar-nav-item.sidebar-expand-contract-icon {
    text-align: initial;
    height: auto;

    img {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
  }
}
```

_core-navigation.scss:

```
$core-nav-width: 100px;
$core-nav-width-wide: 263px;
$core-nav-background-color: #f1f1f1;
$core-nav-background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #20C0BF 0%, #1DC4F0 52%, #7067CF 100%);
```

However when I apply the `re-core-nav-menu-wide` class to my div I get the 100px width not the 263px one. I have tried to rearrange the commands in .core-nav-width-wide however the result is the same. Here is the compiled CSS: http://pastebin.com/6y1GScTT

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will compile into the following CSS:

```css
.re-core-nav-menu-wide {
  width: 263px;
}
.re-core-nav-menu, .re-core-nav-menu-wide {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #20C0BF 0%, #1DC4F0 52%, #7067CF 100%);
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

As you can see ***there is a*** `width` ***setting in both the*** `.re-core-nav-menu-wide` selector and the one that has `.re-core-nav-menu, .re-core-nav-menu-wide`. ***Both are class selectors*** with just a single class in the selector and so they have the ***same specificity***. Thus the `width` setting which is present later in the CSS file wins and so you get only `width: 100px`.

---

**Solution 1:**

To solve the problem, move the `.re-core-nav-menu-wide` ruleset in your Sass code to the end or use a more specific selector.

**Solution 2:**

Another solution would be to form the `.re-core-nav-menu-wide` selector by nesting it under the `.re-core-nav-menu` selector.

Some users may prefer this approach as the nesting makes it more readable than putting the ruleset for wide menu elsewhere in the document.

```css
.re-core-nav-menu {
  width: $core-nav-width;
  /* other stuff */

  &-wide {
    width: $core-nav-width-wide;
    @extend .re-core-nav-menu;
  }
  /* other stuff */
}
```

Comment: &-wide {
    width: $core-nav-width-wide;
    @extend .re-core-nav-menu;
  }
Wont this put a lot of garbage in the CSS since it will have to copy all the properties from .re-core-nav-menu ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the order matters. Since SASS generates the CSS in the same order as defined putting `re-core-nav-menu-wide` before `re-core-nav-menu` in the .scss file results in properties of `re-core-nav-menu` overriding the properties of `re-core-nav-menu-wide`.

I fixed this by changing the order to

```
.re-core-nav-menu {}

.re-core-nav-menu-wide {
    width:.....;
}
```

Comment: Haha, looks like I just about beat you to the answer :D But good that you managed to find it out yourself :)